# the enum for encrypt algorithm name in java

Tags: java, java-11

I found when I use a algorithm to hash text in java, I have to transfer a const value like `SHA-256` into the function like this:

```
public static String getHashText(String passwordToHash,String algorithm) {
        String generatedPassword = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
            byte[] bytes = md.digest(passwordToHash.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            generatedPassword = sb.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return generatedPassword;
    }
```

we should pass the const algorithm name like this:

```
String hashedRefreshToken = MD5Utils.getHashText(request.getRefresh_token(),"SHA-256");
```

I was wonder is there a system Enum for the encrypt algorithm so that I could do it like this:

```
String hashedRefreshToken = MD5Utils.getHashText(request.getRefresh_token(),ENCRYPT.SHA-256);
```

this would be more readable code, I found a class `MessageDigest` but that named `SHA256` not `SHA-256`. is there any system enum for it? why did not have enum? why we need to pass a const string into?

Comment: If it were possible for MessageDigest to take an enum value, it would show up in [MessageDigest documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html).  There is therefore no such thing.   As for "why" - ask the implementors.  But I'd guess it's because the class is extensible to any algorithm that someone wants to provide.

Comment: Whether  ENCRYPT.SHA_256 is more 'readable' than "SHA-256" is a matter of opinion.  I do not find it so.

Comment: Side note: instead of `Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1)` you can simply use `String.format("%02x", bytes[i])`. When using JDK 17, you could replace the entire loop with `String generatedPassword = HexFormat.of().formatHex(bytes);`

Comment: You can have multiple providers, which contribute hashing algorithms that are not supported or required by default. Using an enum would restrict this to only the defaults include (or required) by the Java specification.

Comment: And the string doesn't have to be constant. Currently-used digest algorithms are mostly simple, but signature algorithms are usually "{hash}withRSA", "{hash}withECDSA", "{hash}withECDSAinP1363" etc where hash} varies depending on the key and/or the data -- that would be hard with an enum. Ciphers and key derivations are similar though sometimes using parameters instead of or in addition to naming, MACs and key agreements less so.